# Variable is only storing last value of Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am retrieving all the Phone Numbers from a Firebase realtime database and in the `dataSnapshot` all numbers are being retrieved but when storing the `phoneNumber` in String obj only the last value is being displayed. How is it possible to save all values please? Thanks.

**Code**

```
databasePhone.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot readphone : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.v("tmz",""+ readphone.getKey()); //displays the key for the node
                obj = readphone.child("phoneNumber").getValue().toString();
                try {
                    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput(file_name,MODE_PRIVATE);
                    fileOutputStream.write(obj.getBytes());
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: the string is not an array. if you want to get all the following, you have to create a List<String> to store them in there. And then itterate through that to get all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> phoneNumberList = new ArrayList<>();
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("output.txt");
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String phoneNumber = ds.child("phoneNumber").getValue(String.class);
            phoneNumberList.add(phoneNumber);
            writer.write(phoneNumber);
        }
        //Do what you need to do with your list
        Log.d(TAG, phoneNumberList.toString());
        writer.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
databasePhone.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

See, I got all the phone numbers as strings and added them to a list. Now having the `phoneNumberList`, you can do whatever you need to do with it.